# Diretório antigo ainda permanece

Tags: php, cakephp, host

Peguei um projeto feito em `CakePHP` de um servidor antigo e joguei em um novo, mas o caminho do servidor antigo parece que permanece no script. Joguei todos os arquivos no novo e quando entro na URL, ele me retorna:

```
Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument (ErrorHandler::handleError) to be a valid callback in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 442

Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: set_exception_handler() expects the argument (ErrorHandler::handleException) to be a valid callback in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php on line 445

Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include(/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/upimobco/public_html/lib/Cake/Log/CakeLog.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 546

Fatal error: Class 'CakeLog' not found in /home/daint250/public_html/sitedainterage.com.br/upimob/app/Config/bootstrap.php on line 113
```

Esse diretório **/home/upimobco/public_html** é do servidor antigo. Hoje o caminho é **/public_html/upimob** (está nessa pasta dentro do novo servidor, os arquivos todos).

Não entendo do Cake então não sei aonde que está esse diretório.

Answer (score 0):

Nas configurações,

```
app/config/app.default.php
```

Você terá algo como

```
'App' => [
        'namespace' => 'App',
        'encoding' => env('APP_ENCODING', 'UTF-8'),
        'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US'),
        'base' => false,
        'dir' => 'src',
        'webroot' => 'webroot',
        'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT,

....
```

Apenas precisa verificar o índice `wwwRoot`. Normalmente tem a constante `WWW_ROOT`.

Então procure onde está definida a constante `WWW_ROOT` e defina o novo path.

Normalmente está no `index.php`.

Algo como `define('WWW_ROOT', '/o/path/antigo/deve/estar/aqui/');`

Comment: Na pasta `app/Config` não tem o arquivo app.default.php ;/

Comment: O folder `app/` é um nome genérico padrão. O seu projeto pode estar usando outro nome. Apenas procure `WWW_ROOT` que deve resolver. Use um editor de textos como o notepad++ para buscar em múltiplos arquivos.